# ruby: updating file upload markup - cannot work it out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i have only been introduced to ruby this week on a new clients project and been updating some file inputs however i have got to one that is different and cannot work out how to write into the new markup i need. can anyone lend a hand?

currently it is:

```
  <div class="input inline">
    <% if host_group %>
            <%= label :upload_csv_of_hosts, t(:upload_csv_of_hosts), t(:upload_csv_of_hosts) %>
          <% else %>
            <%= label :upload_csv_of_participants, t(:upload_csv_of_participants), t(:upload_csv_of_participants) %>
          <% end %>
          <div class="markup">
            <%= file_field_tag "csv" %>
            <%=show_required %>
            <%= host_group ? show_info('group/hosts_csv') : show_info('group/participants_csv') %>
          </div>
        </div>
```

which is just using file_field_tag "csv" but i need to build that into this markup like i have for the others i converted, the others i converted was done in a different way that the one above so unsure what that one does and how to implement it into the required markup below.

```
<div class="input inline">
            <%= f.label :filename, t(:uploaded_data), :class => "double" %>
            <div class="markup">
                <%= f.text_field :filename, {:size => 20, :readonly => true, :class => "file_input_textbox", :value => "No File Selected"} %>
                <div class="file_input_div">
                    <%= f.button :browse, :class => "button button-red file_input_button" %>
                    <%= f.file_field :filename, {:size => 20, :class => "file_input_hidden"} %>
                </div>
            </div>
            <%=show_required%>
      <%=show_info('document/uploaded_data') %>
    </div>
```

i have tried this....

```
<div class="input inline">
        <% if host_group %>
    <%= label :upload_csv_of_hosts, t(:upload_csv_of_hosts), t(:upload_csv_of_hosts) %>
  <% else %>
    <%= label :upload_csv_of_participants, t(:upload_csv_of_participants), t(:upload_csv_of_participants) %>
  <% end %>
        <div class="markup">
            <%= f.text_field :csv, {:size => 20, :readonly => true, :class => "file_input_textbox", :value => "No File Selected"} %>
            <div class="file_input_div">
                <%= f.button :browse, :class => "button button-red file_input_button" %>
                <%= f.file_field :csv, {:size => 20, :class => "file_input_hidden"} %>
            </div>
        </div>
        <%=show_required %>
  <%= host_group ? show_info('group/hosts_csv') : show_info('group/participants_csv') %>
</div>
```

but i get the following error:

```
undefined local variable or method `f' for #<#<Class:0x00000007672a58>:0x00000007631a30>
```

its 1:25am and really want to crack this, so very thankful to any helpers!

Thanks

Comment: It's pretty unclear what you want us to help you with.  How exactly do you want to "write into the new markup"? What does that mean exactly? Why are you having trouble with this task? What's tripping you up? You've just posted two `erb` snippets without much explanation of the actual problem or desired result.

Comment: the first part of the code is what it currently is in the file, and the second part is an example of how i need it to be as ive used that on other sections of the system. the other file inputs i changed to my new markup (second example) was not using <%= file_field_tag "csv" %> was doing in a different method, but im not sure how to make <%= file_field_tag "csv" %> into my required markup... make sense? sorry.

Comment: ive updated the question a little, hope i ve explained a little better.

Comment: That error message is really important! `f.text_field` won't work unless it's inside a `form_for @model do |f|` block. Do you have a `form_for` block in the new template? It looks like your problem is outside the code you've posted... So maybe you should go to bed and look at this with fresh eyes in the morning :)

Comment: yep i have <%= form_for(:group, :url => url, :html => {:id => "upload_group_users", :multipart => true, class: "form" }) do %> and yep your maybe right with some fresh eyes, always does the trick normally but i dont really know ruby so might still be in this same boat and you know the feeling when you want to crack something you are keen to crack it :)

Comment: however adding do |f| to form_for got rid of the error and now its loading, it is setting a different  id though... instead of id="csv" its now id="group_csv" any ideas why that might be?

Comment: The form builder generates id's for you.  If you don't like it's conventions, then don't use the form builder. Use the `file_field_tag` helper instead.  But really, those are good conventions that it assumes for you.  You'd do well to embrace them.

Comment: thanks, ill make a note of that in my changes - as the id has changed the ruby team might need to update some code with that new id - thanks for your help! think i might sleep.... soon :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting this error:

> undefined local variable or method `f' for #<#:0x00000007631a30>

When you run this line:

```
<%= f.text_field :csv, {:size => 20, :readonly => true, :class => "file_input_textbox", :value => "No File Selected"} %>
```

And you start your form like this:

```
<%= form_for(:group, :url => url, :html => { :snipped => true }) do %>
```

Then you need this instead:

```
<%= form_for(:group, :url => url, :html => { :snipped => true }) do |f| %>
```

You can't use the form builder object if your `form_for` block doesn't yield it!

---

Also do you see how much of relevant bits of code here were not in your original version of the question? :)